# on_exit and CTRL+C

Tags: c, posix

I've got a small program that opens a file and does some operation on it. I subscribed the file closure to the program termination as follows:

```
static
void exit_handler (int ev, void *arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "bye %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(ev));
    fclose((FILE *)arg);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *out;

    ...

    out = fopen(argv[1], "wt");
    if (out == NULL) {
        perror("Opening output file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    on_exit(exit_handler, out);

    ...
}
```

Trying to execute this I notice that it works properly only if the program terminates normally. In case of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (`SIGINT`) the `exit_handler` callback is not executed.

Isn't that weird? Should I associate a `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` call to the signal handler for `SIGTERM`? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Note that by default on most TTYs, CTRL+C will send `SIGINT` to the foreground process, not `SIGTERM`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart correct. I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `on_exit` isn't specified by POSIX ([`atexit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html) with the same semantics is). Second , the linux manual says:

> The on_exit() function registers the given function  to  be  called 
>   **at normal process termination**, whether via exit(3) or via return from
>   the program's main().

Getting killed by a signal is not a normal exit for a process so callbacks installed with `on_exit` and `atexit` aren't implicitly called.

Comment: In fact `atexit` is defined by the ISO C standard, so it exists even on non-POSIX implementations.

Comment: "Getting killed" is poor terminology.  In fact, the process receives a signal and the default signal handler that the C library links into *your executable* is what terminates the program, thereby, the program is not "killed" and the signal could be ignored.

Comment: I should mention that there are signals that cannot be caught or ignored, ike SIGKILL, that will cause your program to be killed by the kernel without any notification or ability to call atexit handlers.

Answer (score 6):

`on_exit` will not be invoked for `SIGTERM` signals. You need to add a handler for it with `signal`. For example:

```
void signalHandler(void)
{
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler);
}
```

Also note that `SIGKILL` can not be caught by design.

Comment: The `signalHandler` here can simply `exit(0)`, which will call the `atexit` handlers.

Answer (score 4):

No, and in fact what you want is impossible. The signal generated by Ctrl+C is **asynchronous**, meaning it could occur between any two machine instructions in your program depending on when Ctrl+C is hit. As such, unless your program is thoroughly avoiding calling async-signal-unsafe functions anywhere in the main program flow, it's illegal to call async-signal-unsafe functions from the signal handler. `exit` is async-signal-unsafe, as is most of the default cleanup activity it does (like flushing/closing open files). I would expect the `atexit` function you want to register (`atexit`, not `on_exit`, is the correct name for this function) is also going to want to do async-signal-unsafe things.

If you need to perform cleanup when exiting based on a signal, you need to install a signal handler that does not `exit` itself, but instead sets a global volatile flag that your main program flow will later inspect (and `exit` if it's true).

Answer (score 2):

From [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/on_exit) of `on_exit`,

> The on_exit() function registers the given function to be called at
>   normal process termination, whether via exit(3) or via return from the
>   program's main().

So you need to explicity hook up a handler for `SIGTERM` using specific functions from [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html)

Something on the lines of

```
struct sigaction action;

memset (&action, 0, sizeof(action));
action.sa_handler = sigterm_handler;

if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, 0)) 
{
    perror ("sigaction");
    return 1;
}

/* SIGTERM handler. */
static void sigterm_handler (int sig)
{
...
}
```